# How do I use generic views in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to use Django's generic views to make a user registration page. I have the following code in my app's `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from models import Ticket

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^new/$', 'django.views.generic.create_update.create_object', { 'model': User } ),
)
```

Now when I go to that url I get the following:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /new/
auth/user_form.html
```

I have tried making a template to match it but I keep getting that message. Any advice?

Also, I assumed that this would make the template for me. What do I actually put in the template file when I make it?

EDIT: Coming from rails I was mixing templates and views. I am still stuck but I think I need to make a function in my view. Something like:

```
def user_form:
    #stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create the template file using the format `<app_label>/<model_name>_form.html`.  Place this template into the template directory as defined in TEMPLATE_DIRS in your settings file.

In the template file itself, you will need to use the context as defined by the standard ModelForm.

```
{{ form.name.label_tag }} {{ form.name }}
```

Comment: I am trying to do that. Any reason why the error says auth/user_form.html?

Comment: Ok I had my templayes directory wrong. I fixed that and figured the template should be at auth/user_form.html (duh). So now I need figure out how to use the form.name stuff..

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you need to create a view function. you need to provide a template (auth/user_form.html in this case, is also configurable) in your templates directory. The template needs to contain the necessary fields to create the new user object.

see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-create-object) for this.

ans also check out this [similar discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/600748879a4b52da)